# SQL (Multiple SELECT)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contain many ID (1,2,3,4,5,etc) and multiple currencies (123,456,127,etc) and multiple amounts (12,100,1300, etc)

How is it possible to show the total **number** and **amount** per **currency** in separate columns and in the **same line**, as shown below

```
|ID | Total_Number | Total_Sum | Number_Currency_123 | Sum_Currency_123 | Number_Currency_456 | Sum_Currency_456|
```

Comment: Please enter your table definition as well as sample data and desired output

Comment: As Meysam suggested, more info would be helpful, but I think you may need to look at the PIVOT function.

Comment: Generally, this is best done in your presentation layer, *not* the SQL layer. I suspect that you're going to be wanting a dynamic Pivot, and that is not something that someone who is self proclaimed as "new" should be looking at; they can easily introduced security flaws into your system in untrained/unfamiliar hands.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.